# Delete temporary file paths in a object file

Tags: c, embedded

When I modify a comment in a c file, the fingerprint changes due to a link to a temporarty src file:
[image]

In the left the .obj before modification. In the right, the .obj after updating a comment.

Note that I'm using a tasking compiler.

Is there any way to delete these information or to avoid reference to the Temp folder?

Comment: Are you distributing the object files? Do the information appear in the finished linked file?

Comment: Yes I'm distributing object files and libraries. I verified the library, it is changed also. I don't link my objects & libraries, so no idea! but I guess it will be changed too.

Comment: Did you try to set the environment variable for the temporary directory? Please read the compiler's documentation where it puts its temporary files. -- And no, you cannot stop the compiler from including such information, AFAIK. You can only try to use always the same path, that can be "." for example.

Comment: As for the information-leakage problem, make sure your temporary directories are set up in a way that makes them rather generic and therefore anonymous. Perhaps build the release files in a virtual environment of some kind (VM, Docker, etc.) that doesn't reflect your own system. And try *stripping* the object files of information (most compilers either come with options to not add debug information, or have tools that can be used to strip such information).

Comment: I checked the documentation of the compiler, I found that the temp files will be located in TMPDIR ( env var). I'm using windows. What do you think? do you know any free tool that strips such information?